# Attempted addition to default packages at startup not running in RStudio

Tags: r

I want to change my `.Rprofile` file so that the `magrittr` package loads automatically.

Following the threads on Stack Overflow on how to do this  I created a text file with no '.txt' suffix and saved that in my home directory.

The contents of this file are simply

```
library("magrittr")
```

However when I exited R and started up again the error message

```
Error: 1:8: unexpected input
1: library(�
           ^
```

Was displayed on the first line of the window. I get similar messages when I have test code in the .Rprofile file such as

```
print("hello")
```

where the error message reads

```
Error: 1:6: unexpected input
1: print(�
         ^
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Read the content of `help(Startup)` carefully.  There are numerous options, site-wide and per user.

Comment: Thank you @Dirk Eddelbuettel. I did look at that but was a bit overwhelmed. At your prompting I read through it the second time and tried `options(defaultPackages = c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "magrittr"))` and it worked! So for the motivation to be patient with the frantic buzzing in my head that comes when I read R's help pages (often the techspeak is beyond my understanding) thanks!! I also noticed this time that the .Rprofile file was accessible from the home directory in rstudio. Which meant I could manipulate it from within RStudio. That was also an important discovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

First we create a suitable (minimal) `.Rprofile`:

```
edd@max:~$ echo 'library(magrittr); cat("Hello from .Rprofile\n")' > .Rprofile
edd@max:~$
```

Then we test it:

```
edd@max:~$ R -q
Hello from .Rprofile
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 [4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
 [7] "package:magrittr"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"     
> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
edd@max:~$
```

Note how the search path includes package magrittr.

Many more options are detailed in `help(Startup)`.

Comment: Thank you once again @Dirk Eddelbuettel. My first solution worked on my desktop but not my laptop but following your code on this answer got it working on my laptop as well. Thank you. This will make my life much easier. Now I don't have to call `library(magrittr)` every time I want to use `%>%`